# Android studio 3.2 suddenly stopped working?

Tags: android-studio

I have android studio *2.3.3* and *3.2* on my lap

both worked fine  till yesterday when the *3.2* version stopped working .. when i am try to open it i got no thing .. no errors no windows open

i searched for a similar problem but all i got when the program doesn't work for the first time not stopped suddenly while it was working

so any solutions like J D K path won't help because it was already working and the second one ( *2.3.3* ) is still working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the solution worked for me is using another version of android studio 3 like 3.1.3